# JQuery autocomplete - select item and change its color

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using autocompleteTrigger http://jsfiddle.net/dmattes/2YRgW/1/

Is it possible to color the tag after selecting it ?

Example of the text in the Autocomplete:
**Me and Anna went to @barcelona** 
*Barcelona should be in color*

Kind regards,
Dima

Comment: Not unless you planned on being *extremely sneaky*. The problem is that the piece of the string you want to change is actually represented as a value within the input. Your task, should you choose to accept it, is to on `:select(event,ui)`, append a div positioned absolutely over it, pass the value into the div, remove the `ui.label` and test the string for occurrences of `\@[a-Z0-9]`. Then, if we have a match, we'll need to split the string on the match, apply the appropriate element and styles to wrap it, rebuild the string, and then append it to the newly created div.

Comment: The div, when clicked, must call a `focus()` on the input, which on click, would also have to fill the val of the input with the text that we placed into the div. Problem here, is that we'd have to sanitize the data when sending it back so we don't get `html markup in our input val`. That is, unless you don't care about them searching anything again.

Comment: mmm so what do you suggest exactly ? how can it be done ? (facebook is doing it ..)

Comment: The textbox is cleared when you select a value. When is it supposed to be highlighted_

Comment: @Johan After the tag is selected I would like it to appear in the input box colored, adding a class to it or something.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy My purpose is to achieve the same behavior like we see in facebook toaday. This is the most close plug-in that I found. Any suggstions ?

Comment: @sallaboy AFAIK, you cant change parts of the text in the input. If you want to manipluate the entire text, do it in the `open` and `close` events

Comment: @Sallaboy Yes, I have an idea. Let me see if I can throw a mock together.

Comment: @Sallaboy [Obviously this won't work cross browser, but you can see what we're going for here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2YRgW/177/)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy wow :-) after a check you can see that the color disappears after I try continue to add more text. Trying to fix it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can see on the jsfiddle I think this is what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/2YRgW/191/

JS

```
$('input,textarea').autocompleteTrigger({
    triggerStart : '@',
    triggerEnd: '',
    source: [
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ]
});
$('input,textarea').autocomplete({
    select: function(event, ui){
       $('.text2').html(ui.item.value);
       $('.text2').css("background-color","green");
    }
});
​
```

HTML

```
<h2>Textfield</h2>
<input type='text' />

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<h2>Textarea</h2>
<textarea class="text2" col="50" row="3"></textarea>
```

EDIT:

I saw that you asked for the text color to change, not the color of the box.  I changed the fiddler.

http://jsfiddle.net/2YRgW/192/